# Ошибка при сворачивании в трей

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Есть следующая часть кода:

```
procedure TForm1.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DM.TrayIcon1.Visible := true;
  DM.TrayIcon1.Hint := 'Журнал заявок';
  // Убираем с панели задач
  ShowWindow(Handle, SW_HIDE); // Скрываем программу
  ShowWindow(Application.Handle, SW_HIDE); // Скрываем кнопку с TaskBar'а
  SetWindowLong(Application.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE,
  GetWindowLong(Application.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE) or (not WS_EX_APPWINDOW));
end;
```

При компиляции возникает ошибка access violation(см. на рис.).

Возможно ли переполнение памяти в данной процедуре?

[image: Ошибка]

Comment: Ошибка у вас возникает не при компиляции, а при запуске приложения. Запускать надо через дебаг, непосредственно в IDE. Тогда вы увидите, где именно возникла ошибка. Увидите где - дополните свой вопрос этой информацией, а так можно много гадать. Навскидку - dm еще не инициализирован.

Comment: судя по тому, что читается адрес близкий к нулю, то скорее всего так и есть.